# Summing two columns together (each cell separately)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using Excel and I've just started using vba in Excel.

I need to add the values of column I, cells I6:I26 in sheet 1 to column D, cells D1:D21 in sheet 2.

So if I6 = 4 and D1 = 6, and I press the ADD button, D6 will equal to 10. Same goes for the rest of the cells.

I don't want it cell I6 to replace the value of D6, I want it to add to it.

This is the code I have so far for it;

```
Dim r1 as Range, v as variant
Set r1 = Sheets("Sheet2"). Range("D1")
V = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Sheet1.Range("I6"), Sheet2.Range("D1"))
R1 = v
```

I had to do that 20 times..is there anyway to simplify this?

Comment: Yes, use a For loop

Comment: How would I add that to my code?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not just using cell formulas?

Comment: Yes, because the cell values in Column I will be different each time I add it to the cells in column D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [`Evaluate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/application-evaluate-method-excel) the sum of arrays:

```
[Sheet2!D1:D21] = [Sheet1!I6:I26 + Sheet2!D1:D21]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm finding it a bit confusing where you want the result to go.  `Sheet1` has data in `I6:I26` and `Sheet2` has data in `D1:D21`.
You want the first result to go into cell `D6`... on what sheet?  On `Sheet2` so it starts overwriting the old data, in `Sheet1`?  Some other sheet?

This code will place a formula in cell D6 on sheet 1 and drag it down to cell D26.
I've given two types of formula.  A1 notation and R1C1 notation.

A breakdown of the R1C1 notation:
  `RC9` means take data from this row, column 9 - in cell D6 this will be cell I6.
  `R[-5]C4` means take data from 5 rows up in column 4 - in cell D6 this will be D1.

```
Sub Test()

    With Sheet1
        .Range("D6").Formula = "=SUM($I6,Sheet2!$D1)"

        'You could also use R1C1 notation (which is easier if you're looping through rows/columns).
        '.Range("D6").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(RC9,Sheet2!R[-5]C4)"

        .Range("D6:D26").FillDown
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: The OP specified that they don't want to use cell formulas, setting cell formulas through VBA doesn't avoid that...

Comment: I said in my question that I want the cells in column I6:I26 in Sheet 1 to be added to column D1:D21 in Sheet 2

Comment: You did.... you want them added and placed in which cell? `I6 = 4 and D1 = 6`.  So that's cells `I6` and `D1`... the result is `10`, but why is the answer placed in cell `D6`?  Is that `Sheet2 D6`? in which case when you get to adding `I11` and `D6`, which will be after `I6` and `D1`... do you use the original figure or the result of `I6+D1`?

Comment: Still think a formula is a better way to go.. if you want just the figure afterwards you can replace the formula with the value.